# How do I center an action button on alert dialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to center a flat button on alert dialog
I tried the following code but it's not working

```
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('something'),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CupertinoAlertDialog` instead of `AlertDialog` this is much more easy

```
CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text("Alert !",
            style: AppTheme.normalTextStyle()
                .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15)),
        content: Text(
          "Are you sure you want to logout?",
          style: AppTheme.normalTextStyle(),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Yes", style: AppTheme.normalTextStyle()),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LogInScreen()),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("No", style: AppTheme.normalTextStyle()),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
AlertDialog(
  title: FlatButton(
    child: Text('something'),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

or

```
AlertDialog(
  content: FlatButton(
    child: Text('something'),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```